# How to query a DBName if a column in a table has some specific value

Tags: mysql

eImagine this is your database structure when you connect to your server. Most of the time you will have same tables but the values are different. I want to query the Database name if one of the value for my table i.e Tbl1 ColumnName Col1 has value equal to 'Accepted'.

```
DbName1
       Tbl1              
           Col1  -- 'Accepted'    // this are the values col1 holds
                 -- 'Rejected'
                 -- 'In Process'
                 -- 'Awaiting Processing'
DbName2
       Tbl1
           Col1 -- 'NotAccepted'
                -- 'Rejected'

DbName3
       Tb1
           Col1 -- 'NotAccepted'
                -- 'Awaiting Processing'
DbName4
       Tbl1
           Col1 -- 'Accepted' 
                -- 'Rejected'

Expected Result 
DbName1    
DbName4  -- since both DB has Table name Tbl1 whose column Col1 = 'Accepted'
```

In my Sql Environment i have at least 37 Database.

Thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: May we ask how you ended up in this situation?  I'd rather have one table in one database which everything uses to maintain its status.  Then, just issue a single simple `SELECT` statement to get your answer.

Comment: This is a production issue, Imagine every DB is for each Client. Every Client has the same table structure , only few clients where able to do a successful SSIS  dataload which is saved in this table column as 'Accepted'. As there is a lot of DB in production environment i want to find those who were able to do a dataload and find those who could not and fix there issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the database names and tables names and also the column names you can use a UNION solution like this:

```
SELECT distinct dbname
  FROM ( 
    select 'DbName1' as dbname, col1 from DbName1.tb1
    union all
    select 'DbName2' as dbname, col1 from DbName2.tb1
    union all
    select 'DbName3' as dbname, col1 from DbName3.tb1
    union all
    select 'DbName4' as dbname, col1 from DbName4.tb1
    ) dbs
WHERE dbs.col1 = 'Accepted';
```

Although this query will work you should really consider in having a better normalized database instead of 4 (or maybe more) with the same structure and data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as per my example you are right , but want be able to do for all 37 environments that is there.

Comment: There are two options, either you add the other 33 remaining databases/tables on the union or you create a procedure to fetch data from the information schema and with those data query the tables dynamically.